# This Script just loads the next scene instead of playing a sound, waiting, and then loading the next scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This Script just loads the next scene instead of playing a sound, waiting, and then loading the next scene. Someone please help me im not good at c#

```
public class Play_Sound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource soundPlayer;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            Play_This_Sound();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
    }

    public void Play_This_Sound()
    {
        soundPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Play () method will not freeze the program until the end of the sound.
It will simply start playing the sound but then the script will continue to run.
The most elegant solution is with coroutines. If you don't know what they are, search the net - they are a key topic in C #:

```
public AudioSource soundPlayer;

public void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        if (!soundPlayer.isPlaying)
            StartCoroutine(PlayAndLoad());
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayAndLoad()
{
    //Play the sound
    soundPlayer.Play();
    //I wait for the soundPlayer to stop playing.
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => !soundPlayer.isPlaying);
    //Load the scene
    UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}
```

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I would very much appreciate it :)**

Comment: Thankyou so much, i will look up coroutines, and will also look into funtions that are similar to WaitUntil(), and WaitForSeconds()

Comment: @Alfdippers very good idea. If you want, you can vote positively the answer :) If you need more support, I am here!

Comment: Oh, how old are you? I don't even 18: D

Comment: im 18 lol, but i need to get better at c# lol